# Passing properties to a gradle build

Tags: gradle

I admit I am quite new to gradle but I did not expect to be unable to understand something as simple as the example below. I can read the gradle documentation about checking whether a project property have been set or not using a hasProperty(String propertyName) call and I am sitting here and have no idea why something so basic does not work.

I believe my mind must be so much "ant like" oriented that for sure I am missing something ordinary basic

```
task printSystem() << {
    println system
    println "has property: " + hasProperty("system")
}
```

and invoking that task with the command below:

```
$gradle printSystem -Psystem=mySystem
mySystem
has property: null
```

So my questions would be:

1. Why system is printed out but hasProperty returns `null`?
2. How should I check for the existence of the project property called "system"?
3. Is there a different way for testing for a project property as opposed to a system property?
4. How would you pass a system property from the command line?

This is from, the gradle documentation and I believe I am reading it right

19.2.1. Checking for project properties

You can access a project property in your build script simply by using its name as you would use a variable. If this property does not exist, an exception will be thrown and the build will fail. If your build script relies on optional properties the user might set, perhaps in a gradle.properties file, you need to check for existence before you access them. You can do this by using the method hasProperty('propertyName') which returns true or false.

Comment: Have you seen my answer? Does it solve he problem? If so, please accept it.

Comment: Your answer arrived on a Friday afternoon when I was enjoying an end of week drink with my office colleagues :-) I tested your solution today and it worked. I wished the documentation would be clearer say just by putting `project.hasProperty('propertyName')` as opposed to what it shows now. Also when something is supposed to return true or false and returns a null instead adds on to the confusion. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to explicitly invoke `hasProperty` on the `project` instance - without it, `hasProperty` is invoked on some local context. The following example works:

```
task printSystem() << {
    println system
    println "has property: " + project.hasProperty("system")
}
```

1. Because *non-existing* properties (`system` is not defined in the script) are *taken* from the `project` instance. If you won't pass the `system` property, an exception will be thrown on `println`.
2. `project.hasProperty('propName')`
3. Not sure if I understood right, but you can access project properties via the `project` instance and system properties via the `System` class.
4. Using `-D` switch - `gradle -Dprop=value`

Comment: I can spin up my own question for this but how might I check for a System property?  System.hasProperty always returns null as well.  (I've defined a systemProp.example in a gradle.properties file)

Comment: @slifty, `hasProperty` is defined on `project`, not `System`.

Comment: I've asked my question separately, rather than hijacking this comment thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50108534/checking-for-systemprop-values-in-gradle