# Checking that Gradle system properties have been set

Tags: gradle

## The Question

How do I check to see if a System property has been properly set from within a `build.gradle` file?

## The Situation

I have a `gradle.properties` file in my root directory that looks something like this:

```
systemProp.user=exampleUsername
systemProp.password=examplePassword
```

I would like to validate the existence of these properties, something like:

```
if (!System.hasProperty('user')) {
      throw new InvalidUserDataException("No user found in `gradle.properties`; please set one.")
}
```

## Some Code

I've tried the following:

- `project.hasProperty('user')` returns `false`
- `System.properties.get('user')` returns `exampleUsername`
- `System.hasProperty('user')` returns `null`
- `System.properties.get('user') == true` returns true for non-falsey
  values

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `System.properties.containsKey('your_property')` for your purpose. It returns true if a property with the provided key exists, false otherwise. An implementation of this could look like the following:

```
if (!System.properties.containsKey('user')) {
    throw new InvalidUserDataException("No user found in `gradle.properties`; please set one.")
}
```